# Image in image.show isn't showing anything (Python 3 notebook)

Tags: python, image, numpy, url, python-imaging-library

My output doesn't show anything and I honestly can't find out why

This is the full code, but I think the problem is when I'm passing the argument to `aRed, aGreen, aBlue, originalImage = openImage(response.content)`
When I run that code in collab python notebook, my image isn't showing up for some reason! Maybe it's the way I'm passing the URL as an argument in the line above?

```
import numpy
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO

# FUNCTION DEFINTIONS:

# open the image and return 3 matrices, each corresponding to one channel (R, G and B channels)
def openImage(imagePath):
    imOrig = Image.open(BytesIO(imagePath))
    im = numpy.array(imOrig)

    aRed = im[:, :, 0]
    aGreen = im[:, :, 1]
    aBlue = im[:, :, 2]

    return [aRed, aGreen, aBlue, imOrig]

# compress the matrix of a single channel
def compressSingleChannel(channelDataMatrix, singularValuesLimit):
    uChannel, sChannel, vhChannel = numpy.linalg.svd(channelDataMatrix)
    aChannelCompressed = numpy.zeros((channelDataMatrix.shape[0], channelDataMatrix.shape[1]))
    k = singularValuesLimit

    leftSide = numpy.matmul(uChannel[:, 0:k], numpy.diag(sChannel)[0:k, 0:k])
    aChannelCompressedInner = numpy.matmul(leftSide, vhChannel[0:k, :])
    aChannelCompressed = aChannelCompressedInner.astype('uint8')
    return aChannelCompressed


# MAIN PROGRAM:
response = requests.get('https://i.imgur.com/BIOFZNo.png')
print ('*** Image Compression using SVD - a demo')
aRed, aGreen, aBlue, originalImage = openImage(response.content)
# image width and height:
imageWidth = 1000
imageHeight = 1000

#number of singular values to use for reconstructing the compressed image
singularValuesLimit = 160

aRedCompressed = compressSingleChannel(aRed, singularValuesLimit)
aGreenCompressed = compressSingleChannel(aGreen, singularValuesLimit)
aBlueCompressed = compressSingleChannel(aBlue, singularValuesLimit)

imr=Image.fromarray(aRedCompressed,mode=None)
img=Image.fromarray(aGreenCompressed,mode=None)
imb=Image.fromarray(aBlueCompressed,mode=None)

newImage = Image.merge("RGB", (imr,img,imb))

originalImage.show()
newImage.show()
```

There are no errors in compiling the program, it just doesn't show up anything.
Thank you all!
Here is the link to my file: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/12K0nWKRdOpZ3gSfTn0wuP8Y0_UUeUxEE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to specify `.show()` in interactive modes. Just remove that part, and it will work fine.

```
import numpy
from PIL import Image
import requests
from io import BytesIO

# FUNCTION DEFINTIONS:

# open the image and return 3 matrices, each corresponding to one channel (R, G and B channels)
def openImage(imagePath):
    imOrig = Image.open(BytesIO(imagePath))
    im = numpy.array(imOrig)

    aRed = im[:, :, 0]
    aGreen = im[:, :, 1]
    aBlue = im[:, :, 2]

    return [aRed, aGreen, aBlue, imOrig]

# compress the matrix of a single channel
def compressSingleChannel(channelDataMatrix, singularValuesLimit):
    uChannel, sChannel, vhChannel = numpy.linalg.svd(channelDataMatrix)
    aChannelCompressed = numpy.zeros((channelDataMatrix.shape[0], channelDataMatrix.shape[1]))
    k = singularValuesLimit

    leftSide = numpy.matmul(uChannel[:, 0:k], numpy.diag(sChannel)[0:k, 0:k])
    aChannelCompressedInner = numpy.matmul(leftSide, vhChannel[0:k, :])
    aChannelCompressed = aChannelCompressedInner.astype('uint8')
    return aChannelCompressed


# MAIN PROGRAM:
response = requests.get('https://i.imgur.com/BIOFZNo.png')
print ('*** Image Compression using SVD - a demo')
aRed, aGreen, aBlue, originalImage = openImage(response.content)
# image width and height:
imageWidth = 1000
imageHeight = 1000

#number of singular values to use for reconstructing the compressed image
singularValuesLimit = 160

aRedCompressed = compressSingleChannel(aRed, singularValuesLimit)
aGreenCompressed = compressSingleChannel(aGreen, singularValuesLimit)
aBlueCompressed = compressSingleChannel(aBlue, singularValuesLimit)

imr=Image.fromarray(aRedCompressed,mode=None)
img=Image.fromarray(aGreenCompressed,mode=None)
imb=Image.fromarray(aBlueCompressed,mode=None)

newImage = Image.merge("RGB", (imr,img,imb))

originalImage
```

OriginalImage will be displayed. For new image, in next code cell:

```
newImage
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! But could you explain why I shouldn't use ```.open()``` in that case?

Comment: That is how colab notebook which is copy of jupyter notebook is designed. You don't need to use show(), or print(), and the sort.